# Why is tf.multinomial used on logits and what is its exact output for a log softmax input?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a query, I was reading a code online on github and encountered this line,

```
pi = tf.squeeze(tf.multinomial(logits,1), axis=1)
```

Here logits is the log softmax output of a MLP. What exactly is happening here ?

Here is the full code for the function:

```
def mlp_categorical_policy(x, a, hidden_sizes, activation, output_activation, action_space):
    act_dim = action_space.n
    logits = mlp(x, list(hidden_sizes)+[act_dim], activation, None)
    logp_all = tf.nn.log_softmax(logits)
    pi = tf.squeeze(tf.multinomial(logits,1), axis=1)
    logp = tf.reduce_sum(tf.one_hot(a, depth=act_dim) * logp_all, axis=1)
    logp_pi = tf.reduce_sum(tf.one_hot(pi, depth=act_dim) * logp_all, axis=1)
    return pi, logp, logp_pi
```

Comment: tf.multinomial usually used for dropout but here is a bit strange. Is it possible to paste more part of the code?

Comment: @Amir I have pasted the function in which it is called. It's part of a Vanilla Policy Gradient code. As per tf docs, this just picks a index out of a multinomial distribution, but isn't that kind of random. Should we not pick the maximum probability index of the logits ?

Comment: Since "why" is not technical its quite hard to understand and is more of a domain question. It is indeed random, `tf.multinomial` is a shorthand for `tf.random.multinomial` which just draws samples from a multinomial distribution (which are unnormalized log probabilities in this case)